# Asynchronous distributed file transfers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to build a system where we have a set of machines produce unique files, lets call them PRODUCERS and a set of machines receive these files which we call CONSUMERS. Any machine from the PRODUCERS can send files to one or more of the CONSUMERS[ based on some hash mechanism]. I need to build a mechanism which ensures that the file delivery happens in a guaranteed mannner. i.e. Producers or consumers may crash/reboot and be able to continue from where they left off. Is there any fool proof scalable way to implement this, it seems to be quite a common need in any fault tolerant system? The number of producers and consumers are expected to increase/decrease on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is probably most easily implemented using some form of message passing. You might want to take a look at http://www.zeromq.org; I've worked with this library myself and can whole-heartedly recommend it.

On a side-note: if you don't need to use C++, picking up some [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/) might be interesting in your case.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds a bit like the replication mechanism of the [Google File System](http://labs.google.com/papers/gfs.html) architecture. You'll be most interested in section 3.1 and 3.2 of the paper, together with the illustration in figure 2.

A summary (with simplifications) as it applies to your case:

1. **PRODUCER** sends the data, waits for a reply.
2. **CONSUMER**(s) reply, "I have received all the data."
3. **PRODUCER** sends a "finish write" command, waits for a reply.
4. **CONSUMER**(s) reply, "I have flushed the data to disk."
5. Now (and only now) consider the data, "saved."

GFS as described in the paper implements a number of optimizations, including pipelining the write to consumers instead of splitting one machine's bandwidth across *n* machines simultaneously.

To further your safety guarantees through crashes, you can make the write operations idempotent using an [Intent Log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intent_log). This could either be at the producer's end only (you retry after a timeout, for instance), or at the consumers' end as well (on reboot, continue the operation).